# In Winforms, how do I override the OnDropDown method of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use the method found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/multicolumncombo.aspx) to create a custom combo box that displays a selection grid instead of the built in list drop down.  The solution basically just overrides the OnDropDown method, creates a form and shows it.  However, I'm finding that the built in drop down is also displayed when I click the down arrow.  My form is drawn over it but it does show up for a quick second.  Any ideas?

```
protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
{
  DropDownForm dropDown = new DropDownForm();

  // Locate at correct location.
  DropDownForm.Location = ...;

  DropDownForm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation, I would recommend the simplicity of a custom user control.  Instead of trying to circumvent default behavior (for which the control was designed for), it would be trivial to create a user control with a text box and a button that opens your grid.  In fact, you could then bundle your grid with your drop down and have a completely reusable control.

Comment: I was afraid that would be someone's answer.  It shouldn't be too hard.  I'm just worried about missing something when trying to mimic the ComboBox's behavior.  Anyway, is there a down arrow image included in the framework or Windows that I can legally distribute?

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid of that answer -- it's the right way to do it, and you want to do it the right way, correct?  Check out http://www.iconfinder.com for TONS of graphics and icons to use in your project.  Many of these icons have open licenses for distribution.